# Detail section of crystal report printed twice on Dot Matrix printer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to print on Dot matrix printer, report is printed fine but detail section of crystal report is printed twice.

but same crystal report printed fine on laser printer not twice.

Note : i attached image bellow of report that[image] are printed on 
       Dot matrix printer

Comment: Most likely a printer driver issue. What version of CR? What type of printer (make/model)?

Comment: crystal report verson - SAP Crystal Reports,version for Visual Studio 2010 version-13.0.1.220, printer (make/model) - campagnolo_1

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure you have the latest CR for VS version. I thinnk they're up to 13.0.8 now
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

2) Make sure you have the latest updates for the printer driver

3) Make sure the printer driver is Unicode compliant

4) Experiment with the "No Printer" option and Dissociate Formatting Page Size and Printer Paper Size option